# Issue with Datatables Header colour

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm using dataTable in my project and using jquery UI as styling framework, I wish to change the table header colour so I used `.ui-datatable-header` to change the colour, but it does not have any effects on my table, please suggest me some solution,
Here is working [demo](http://live.datatables.net/lavodilu/1/edit)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I.e not link to an example bur show the relevant code and your effort; besides that nested CSS does not work. Simply target the element and set a new value to the appropriate attribute, you can find out how by inspecting the element in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is not class with name `.ui-datatable-header` in dataTables jQueryUI styling framework. And in fact you've written wrong code, you cannot nested style.

```
.DTFC_LeftFootWrapper {
    display:none;
  .ui-datatable-header{ background: blue;} 
}
```

To change the color of the table header just use the following css

```
table.dataTable thead th.ui-state-default {
  background: blue;
}
```

[Updated demo](http://live.datatables.net/pepigici/2/)

Comment: Thanks @prashant its working. Thanks for the help i wanted to change the background i was able to figure it out with yur help 
 http://live.datatables.net/cejoquja/1/edit